# Send bytes in Python with serial

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to send 10 bits thought raspberry pi USB port splitting them in two bytes and manipulating the first for identifying it with this code:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyACM0',
    baudrate = 38400,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1
    )

while 1:
    val=input()

    a= bytes((val>>8) | 0xA0)
    a1=bytes(val & 0x00ff)

    ser.write(a)
    ser.write(a1)
```

but it seems to send the ASCII code instead of the binary data and I don't find a way to solve the problem! 
Can anybody help me please??
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I've now solved the problem, the right code is:

```
val=input()

a= chr((val>>8) | 0xA0)
a1=chr(val & 0x00ff)

ser.write(a)
ser.write(a1)
```